# How to restrict Html5 input to enter single quote and colon

Tags: html, forms, jsp, validation

I have created 1 jsp page that contain html form, **while submitting html form** i have checked input string for not contain any single quote(') or colon(:)

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return toValidate('demo')>
    <input name="demo" id="demo" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript function:**

```
function toValidate(id){
    var str = "";
    for(var i=0; i<val.length;i++) {
     if (val[i] == "'" || val[i] == ":") {
      alert(" ' and : not allowed");
      return false;
     }
     else
     {
      str =str+val[i];
      document.getElementById(id).value=str;
     }      
}

 }
```

**My question is that how can i restrict input field using html5 pattern...?**

Comment: Using pattern you can specify the values you can allow . so what conditions you are matching with your input field ?

Comment: '@san krish' i want to restrict single quote and colon...

Comment: The [tag:jquery-validate] plugin has nothing to do with this question.  Please be more careful when tagging by reading their descriptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I modified your HTML code with the validation using HTML5 regular expression

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="demo" type="text" id="demo" pattern="[^':]*$" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

See fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mzDt9/

Comment: Been searching EVERYWHERE for some kind of JS or whatever, and this one-liner does exactly what I want, BRILLIANT! +1

Comment: @Vijay if i want to restrict single quotes, double quotes, question mark and equal sign, what would I need to change on the code that you provided?